# How to put the whole name of an author in the Last part of a bibliography entry?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibentry

The point of my question is for the cases when an author is an institution, of which name should no contain any First part, as far as I'm concerned. (as in First / von / Last)

When I try with

```
author = {Ministère de l'Éducation nationale et de la Jeunesse},
```

in my `.bib` entry, I get an ugly

> Ministère de l’Éducation nationale et de la JEUNESSE

(with capital 'J' a little bit bigger than the other capital letters) in the bibliography of my document and, even worse, the key to this entry is automatically set to `dlnedlJ19`.

What I would like to have is the whole institution name to be written with capital letters (i.e. being considered as the Last part as a whole) and, for instance, the first capital 'M' to be part of the entry key.

How can I do so? I have tried pretty much everything dealing with the order of the words of that name and using commas, to try to disable the First part for BibTeX.

A MWEB for this question could be

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\prce.bib}
@misc{BO-programme-seconde,
  author = {Ministère de l'Éducation nationale et de la Jeunesse},
  title = {{Programme de SNT}},
  month = jan,
  year = {2019},
  howpublished = {https://cache.media.education.gouv.fr/file/SP1-MEN-22-1-2019/08/5/spe641_annexe_1063085.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{BO-programme-seconde}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\prce}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407 to see how you can provide a "better" question in the future.

Comment: OK. I've done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `author = {{Ministère de l'Éducation nationale et de la Jeunesse}},`, i.e. "**nested curly bracket**" (`{{text}}`), aka "**double curly brackets**".

### Related

- [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10808)
- [Double parenthesis in BibTeX record](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327386)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I did try to look for related questions first, though. Maybe mine could be considered as a duplicate, then. (The difference between a corporation and an institution is too slight to worth two actual different questions)